# Google Chrome debugger skip breakpoint

Tags: javascript, debugging, google-chrome

I am currently trying to debug a js script in chrome, I put a breakpoint in the script and it breaks properly when I use only one tab, but on a second tab it doesn't break even though I see the break point in the code.

Comment: did you put a `debugger;` statement at this line ?

Comment: no just a click and add breakpoint, also I see the breakpoint in the two tabs

Comment: I have the same problem suddenly. `debugger;` statements don't work either. It simply won't stop on a breakpoint at all, and when I try to put a breakpoint it puts it on a different line from what I select. There is a serious disconnect happening here.

Comment: having no luck debugging karma tests

Comment: Are you still having this problem? I am not able to duplicate it so I wonder if it was a problem that has since been fixed. If you are still having the problem what version are you using?

Comment: i gave up on this problem and debugged my code without debugger

Comment: I have this currently. Very frustrating :(

Comment: It's rare that has ever really happened. Just close and re-open Chrome, it has always fixed that for me.

Comment: Hi all, Are you using plain javascript or some framework? I supposed that you did but just in case did you put a console.log to see if that line is executed? Can you put here some example about your code to try to reproduce it?

Comment: Can you try to do ctrl+f5 on the second tab. And reclick f12 to make sure that you are on devtool related to the current tab

Answer (score 1):

Did you use the pretty print option when viewing the source:

[image]

I have noticed that the formatted copy can get out of sync. I remove all of the breakpoints, close both the formatted tab and the original tab (in sources), then open the original, click the pretty print option, and add back my break points.

I haven't looked in depth as to why this is happening, it's just what I've experienced and the work around I found (assuming it's something with the cached version of the formatted source).

Answer (score 0):

you have to open a new debugger window for each tab that you want to debug :)