# WebStorm debug mode doesn't hit breakpoints

Tags: google-chrome, webstorm

I have WebStorm successfully launching my app when I hit debug. It runs the app in chrome and Chrome tells me that that tab is in debug mode.

But it will not break on any breakpoint. I am using Ext JS and in the root app.js I have a breakpoint on the launch: function (which is being called) and that does not drop me into the debugger.

Does the WebStorm debugger not work with Ext JS?

Comment: may be related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17059465/google-chrome-debugger-skip-breakpoint

Comment: please, check http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-8096 - does it look similar to your issue? If not, then, please, provide a sample project that shows up the problem

Comment: @lena It could be the same thing. In my case it is the root app.js, but in the launch function. I'll watch for a bug fix on that reported bug. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not having luck hitting breakpoints when running karma test specs :(

Answer (score 3):

I have the same situation as yours, except that I'm building my app using Backbone.js and RequireJs and the app is running on localhost. My app can run in debug mode in Chrome but the breakpoints cannot be hit.

I solve the problem by mapping the Remote URL and my local directory. You can define this in your JavaScript debug configuration profile in the Run->Edit Configurations.

You can refer to this wonderful tutorial: [Debugging your JavaScript app using WebStorm](http://www.gamefromscratch.com/post/2012/08/17/Debugging-with-JavaScript-with-WebStorm.aspx).

Happy debugging!

Comment: How exactly did you do mapping? What file to what URL?

Comment: Just an FYI, I had incorrectly mapped my web-code folder to a linux path name (my web server is running Linux). When I changed it to a URL, it worked. For example I used http://myserver.mydomain.com/homepage.html